# How did 'to treat' evolve from 'to draw, drag, move'?

Tags: etymology

> [treat (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=treat&allowed_in_frame=0)    ... frequentative of ***trahere*** (past participle tractus) "to pull, draw" (see [tract](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tract&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.1)).  ...
>
> [tract (n.1)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tract&allowed_in_frame=0) ... from stem of ***trahere*** "to pull, draw," from PIE root *tragh- "to draw, drag, move" ...

The foregoing shows my research: 'treat' <= ***trahere*** <= PIE root *tragh-. What are some right ways of interpreting this evolution, to make it feel reasonable and intuitive? I struggle to see the bigger picture or key notion that connects or overlies them?

Comment: ***Treat*** : c. 1300, "***negotiate, bargain, deal with***," from Old French traitier "deal with, act toward; set forth (in speech or writing)" (12c.), ***from Latin tractare "manage, handle, deal with, conduct oneself toward," originally "drag about, tug, haul.*** . I think that the original *pull, drag* is a good figurative reference for *bargaining.*

Comment: Also, conceptually, "treating" a disease can be thought of as "drawing it out" of the body,  like removing a parasite. If I am informed correctly, the use of leeches was premised on that disease paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Already in Latin the verb tractare developed a lot of uses. Dictionaries mostly give up to 10 uses. So if you want to understand the various semantic paths you have to study the various uses of the verb and the example material in the Latin dictionary. But it is possible to understand the various developments.
[Pons tracto](http://en.pons.com/translate/latin-german/tracto)